# How do I disable and re-enable a button in with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I can easily disable a javascript button, and it works properly.  My issue is that when I try to re-enable that button, it does not re-enable.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startCombine(startButton) {

        startButton.disabled = 'true';

        startButton.disabled = 'false';

    }
</script>
<input type='button' id='start' value='Combine Selected Videos'
onclick='startCombine(this);'>
```

Why isn't this working, and what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`true` and `false` are not meant to be strings in this context.

You want the literal `true` and `false` `Boolean` values.

```
startButton.disabled = true;

startButton.disabled = false;
```

The reason it *sort of* works (disables the element) is because a non empty string is *truthy*. So assigning `'false'` to the `disabled` property has the same effect of setting it to `true`.

Comment: How to enable button that was disabled in HTML  <Button disabled/>

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
function checkusers()
{
   var shouldEnable = document.getElementById('checkbox').value == 0;
   document.getElementById('add_button').disabled = shouldEnable;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

document.getElementById('btn').disabled = !this.checked"

```html
<input type="submit" name="btn"  id="btn" value="submit" disabled/>

<input type="checkbox"  onchange="document.getElementById('btn').disabled = !this.checked"/>
```