# HTML checkbox & Submit Button by Agreeing on Terms and Condition

Tags: html, authentication, checkbox, submit, wireless

I'm designing an html page for WiFi authentication and I would like to introduce in this page a Checkbox and Submit button, upon reading the Terms and Condition and Checking the CheckBox, the Submit button will  be active.

Is this doable?

thanks,

Comment: Of Course its Doable .. 
Look into Javascript .. <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394562/how-do-i-disable-and-re-enable-a-button-in-with-javascript

Comment: Are you using any JS framework ? Anyway I think you shoud search google for this and found millions of answers ^^

Comment: Hello, not I'm not using any JS.. it's only html code

Comment: The link you provided it doesn't work... nothing it shows in the HTML page :)

Comment: I have tried all of this, non of them are working:(

Comment: <script>
function checkusers()
{
   var a = document.getElementById(`checkbox`).value;
   if(a ==0)
   {
      document.getElementById(`add_button"`).disabled = false;
   }
   else 
   {
      document.getElementById(`add_button`).disabled = true;
   }
}
</script>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {
    
      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      }
  
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="disableSubmit()">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)">  I Agree Terms & Conditions
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank  you very much for your fast response, yes this is what I'm intended to do.. highly appreciated your efforts.

Comment: Hello, I have noticed the button is enabled as soon as the page loaded... it will be disabled only upon clicking/activating the CheckBox...

Comment: So you want the checkbox will be checked when the page is loaded. right?

Comment: when the page is loaded the checkbox should be unchecked and the submit button should be disabled as well. do you want me to share the whole code with you?

Comment: Thats what we are doing. right?
Share me the code So that i can do modifications directly.

Comment: Hi, please find link below.. https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/a436182ad4e7ddbb78dc6b7a220fcaa820140203103742/9991b050cf31f164a08e7ca144308ac320140203103742/7cbaf2

Comment: Add the following line in your loadAction() function (at line 78 in your code). It will work.

document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;

Comment: I have added it, but still it doesn't work..                        }
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
function loadAction(){
     var url = window.location.href;
     var args = new Object();
     var query = location.search.substring(1);
     var pairs = query.split("&");
     for(var i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){
          var pos = pairs[i].indexOf('=');
          if(pos == -1) continue;
          var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos);
          var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);
          args[argname] = unescape(value);
     }

Comment: That line should be the first line in that function (not outside).
I'm sharing the file, copy and save it as html file.
http://vbreddy.my3gb.com/testform.txt

Comment: Yes, this works pefectly. I hope once I upload it to the WLC it will works fine. Appreciate your effort and forgive me as I'm not script-er or html coder :)